# Proof verification: Convergent series using ratio theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Proof attempt below horizontal line. Is it complete?

Prove that if $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j$ is a positive series and satisfies that $\displaystyle \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j} = H < 1$
the series is convergent.

---

It's given that the series is positive and therefore $H$ will as well: $0<H<1$. Hence the fraction $\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}$ will lie somewhere between $0$ and $1$ on the real number line. Let us take a number $K$ as an upper limit to $H:H<K<1$. Given an arbitrary $j\geq J$ we know that $\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}<K$. We can write the following:

\begin{align*}
  j = J:    &\Rightarrow \  \frac{a_{J+1}}{a_J}     \    < K
            \\
            &\Rightarrow \  a_{J+1}                 \: \ < K (a_J)
            \\
  j = J+1:  &\Rightarrow \  \frac{a_{J+2}}{a_{J+1}} \    < K
            \\
            &\Rightarrow \  a_{J+2}                 \: \ < K (a_{J+1}) \ < K^2 (a_J)
            \\
  j = J+2:  &\Rightarrow \  \frac{a_{J+3}}{a_{J+2}} \    < K
            \\
            &\Rightarrow \  a_{J+3}                 \: \ < K (a_{J+2}) \ < K^3 (a_{J})
\end{align*}

Let us look at the sum of them: $a_J + a_{J+1}+ a_{J+2}+ a_{J+3} + ... <a_J+a_J K + a_JK^2 + a_JK^3 + ...
=a_J(1+K+K^2+K^3+...)$

It's a convergent geometric series!

$$\sum_{j=J}^\infty a_j < a_J \sum_{j=0}^\infty K^n$$

Since $K<1$ and $J$ is an arbitrary number we have that $\sum_{j=J}^\infty a_j$ converges. The series $\sum_{j=0}^J a_j$ is a finite sum given a number $J$ hence the following series is also convergent:

$$\sum_{j=0}^J a_j+\sum_{j=J}^\infty a_j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j$$

Comment: Note that $H$ can be zero – however that does not affect the rest of your argument.

Comment: Thank, you I will change to $0\leq H$ instead.

Comment: I just realized, if the series is positive and zero is neither positive or negative, wouldn't that mean that $\frac{a_j+1}{a_j}> 0$ $\forall j$? Also, the elements may approach zero but no element will be $0$, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The principle is correct, you must end up comparing your series to a geometric series to demonstrate convergence.

There is one key issue in your proof though.  $J$ can't be arbitrary.  It must be selected so that the crucial inequality $ a_{j+1}/a_{j} \lt K$ holds for all $j \geq J $.  You can make this selection because of the limit assumption.  But $J$  itself can't be arbitrary.  All sorts of wild things can happen at the beginning of a sequence.

Comment: Right, I phrased it incorrectly. Thank you.